# Best way to design form with jquery tabs scenario

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a large viewmodel for my `GET` action.

I have a tabs jquery plugin in my view.

On form submit to the `POST` action, the posted model will have some null values depending on which tab the user selected.

`ModelState.IsValid` will always evaluate to false since the posted model will always contain null values (from the fields in the hidden tabs).

How to make so that `ModelState.IsValid` evaluates to true? Do I need some manual checking here and skip the `ModelState.IsValid` completely?

How to tell the model binder that the fields in the hidden tabs should not be null?

Is there a way to tell the viewmodel that it is ok that some values will be null when passed from the view to the actionmethod so that `ModelState.IsValid` evaluates to true?

I tried posting to different actions with different viewmodels (subsets of the larger one), depending on which tab that was chosen, but this gives me problems when the view needs to be redisplayed in case of an error and I have to redirect to the `GET` action and by doing this I loose my model state. Also if I redisplay the view in the `POST` action the URL will not be the same as the one from the `GET` action.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I've found this solution [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/02/19/partial-validation-in-aspnet-mvc-2/)

Suppose you have the following two parts of codes

```
public class ViewModel
{
//Validation Part A
    string A1 { get; set; }
    string A2 { get; set; }
    string A3 { get; set; }
//Validation Part B
    string B1 { get; set; }
    string B2 { get; set; }
    string B3 { get; set; }
}
```

You can filter the `ModelState[key].Errors` in the Controller

```
public virtual ActionResult PartA(ViewModel command)
{
    string[] ValidationPartAKeys = {"A1", "A2", "A3"}
    foreach(string key in ModelState.Keys.Where(
        x => !ValidationPartAKeys.Contains(x))
    {
        ModelState[key].Errors.Clear();
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid) // Should be validating regarding only to Part A's properties here
    {
        //Do Stuffs
    }
}
```